# Why does iterating over a BufReader.lines() in a Server and Client doesn't end until I explicitly break the loop in the server

Tags: rust, server, tcp, client

I'm currently learning about the `TcpStream` and `TcpListener` so I'm trying to explore a little bit about it.

I have encounter this problem, specificially, I have this code in `server.rs`

```rust
    let my_listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8000").unwrap();

    for connection_stream in my_listener.incoming(){
        println!("Got a connection");
        let mut my_connection = connection_stream.unwrap();


        let some_buffer = BufReader::new(&my_connection);
        let buffer_data = some_buffer.lines();

        for data in buffer_data{
            println!("Data: {}", data.unwrap());
            
            // If I put `break` here, everything would work.
        }

        my_connection.write(b"Hello World").unwrap();

        println!("A Successful Interaction");
    }
```

and this in `client.rs`

```rust
    loop{
        let mut my_stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8000").unwrap();
        
        let mut my_input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut my_input).unwrap();
        
        my_stream.write(my_input.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        
        let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&my_stream);

        for values in buf_reader.lines(){
            println!("{}", values.unwrap());

            // but if I put `break` here, nothing really happens.
        }
        
        println!("This will not print until a connect has been establish");
    
    }
```

If I entered any value in any instance of any client, say `watermelon`, this would be the result:

**Client**

```
[1] watermelon // my input
[3] // can't input anymore
```

**Server**

```
[0] Got a Connection
[2] Data: watermelon
```

After a connection has been establish, `[0]` would print in the server, then after I input `[1]`, the server would print out `[2]` but then i can't input anymore `[3]`.

If I add `break` in the `server.rs` `.lines()` loop , it would now work. However, If I add `break` in the client `.lines()` loop, it still wouldn't work.

Why is this happening? and what are the different ways I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over `lines()` will not stop when there is no more data in the stream; it will block until more data is sent, and only stop when the stream is closed. So the client is waiting for the server to send data and the server is waiting for the client to send data, hence a deadlock.

You can spawn a thread that will read data from stdin and send it to the stream, and another thread will print the data received from the stream.

Comment: When I remove the `lines()` for-loop in the `client.rs` and create multiple instances of the client, the `println!("A Successful Interaction");` would print out in the server terminal, including the data passed by the different clients even though I'm iterating over `lines()` in the server. Doesn't this mean that `lines()` can stop iterating after reading everything? or am I missing something?

Comment: @BeepBoopBit It can, but only after the stream is closed as I said in the answer.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand it. Thanks, I've tested it by moving the `my_stream` definition in the `client.rs` outside of the `loop` and created multiple instances of the client. Though I can write in the stream on other instances, the server won't read them. May I ask where can I read this kind of information? it seems like `the [BufRead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) documentation doesn't tell that it waits.